# Bash - how to count number of instructions?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, assembly, build

I have a number of *.s assembly files. I would like to count how many instructions they contain. For example, to count all *mul* instructions I do:

```
cat *.s | grep -P '\t'"mul" | wc -l
```

which gives me a compound number of all mul instructions.

I would like to have an output like:

```
mul: 893
add: 12054
sub: 2356
...
```

The problem is that there is no table of instructions supported by a target platform. Each target platform has different set of instructions. The supported instructions must be deduced from existed assembly files. Can I do it in Bash only without Perl/Python foundry?

Comment: You don't want Perl or Python, but what about sed, awk, GNU coreutils?

Comment: "operand" != "operation"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all of them like this:

```
grep -hP '^[ \t]+[a-z]*' *.s | sed 's/^[ \t]\+\([a-z]*\).*/\1/' | sort | uniq -c
```

Edit: I changed this to work with the example provided by SiegeX.

Output:

```
1 call
6 mov
1 push
1 ret
2 syscall
2 xor
```

Comment: Unnecessary use of cat. Try `sed [expression] *.s | ... ` instead.

Comment: @Brent: your current code breaks when there are more than one .s files because grep will prepend the filename. Use `grep -Ph` to inhibit that.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your instructions are all indented from the other code by use of white space (tab is OK), then this `awk` 1-liner will work:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]]+/{a[$1]++}END{for(op in a){print op,a[op]}}' /path/to/*.s
```

#### Input

```
$ cat asm.s
section .text
global _start, write
write:
  mov al,1 ;write syscall
  syscall
  ret
_start:
  mov rax,0x0a68732f6e69622f
  push rax
  xor rax,rax
  mov rsi,rsp
  mov rdi,1
  mov rdx,8
  call write

exit: ; just exit not a function
  xor rax,rax
  mov rax,60
  syscall
```

#### Output

```
$ awk '/^[[:space:]]+/{a[$1]++}END{for(op in a){print op,a[op]}}' ./*.s
push 1
xor 2
ret 1
mov 6
syscall 2
call 1
```

Comment: @Brent: I would highly suggest it. awk's associative arrays and field grabbing are very,very powerful. `sed` is a bit cumbersome when it comes to singling out a particular field.

Answer (score 1):

Bash 4 without any external utilities:

```
declare -A c;while IFS=$'\n' read -r t;do [[ ! $t =~ ^[[:space:]] ]] && continue;w=($t);((c[${w[0]}]++));done<asm.s;for op in ${!c[@]};do echo $op ${c[$op]};done
```

To do multiple files, wrap the `while` loop in a `for f in *.s` loop with the while's `done` like this: `done < "$f"` or do the while's `done` like this: `done < <(cat *.s)` instead of the `for f`.

Slightly shorter to count the first word on each line without regard to indentation:

```
declare -A c;while read -ra t;do [[ $t ]]&&((c[${t[0]}]++));done<asm.s;for op in ${!c[@]};do echo $op ${c[$op]};done
```

Still, it's longer than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the hell of it, SiegeX's awk answer in Perl

```
perl -n '/^\s+(\w+)/&&$a{$1}++;END{print map{"$_ $a{$_}\n"}keys%a}' ./*.s
```

Because "anything you can do I can do in a manner which more closely resembles line noise" (-:

Answer (score 0):

grep -Eo '\w+' /source.file | uniq -c

Comment: sorry -- sort is needed :
grep -Eo '\w+' /source.file | sort | uniq -c